# BASH script presenting IF syntax error

Tags: bash, scripting

```
for k in {794..800}
if [  -f    "vesta_$k.xyz"    ]
then
      do
         mkdir $k
         mv vesta_$k.xyz $k/vesta.xyz
         cd $k/
                 <<COMMANDS>>
         cd ..
      done
fi
```

PS vesta_$k.xyz is a sequence of files. The problem is at the first line of the IF command.

Comment: Put a ; at the end of if statement: `if [  -f    "vesta_$k.xyz"    ];`

Comment: @bangal You don't need the `;` when there is a line break.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic for Server Fault but in any case, http://www.shellcheck.net is a great resource for diagnosing shell scripting problems (such as syntax errors).

Answer (score 2):

`if.. then.. fi` should be fully inside `for.. do.. done`, you cannot cross them

```
for        k in {794..800}
do
    if     [ -f "vesta_$k.xyz" ]
    then
           mkdir "$k"
           mv "vesta_$k.xyz" "$k/vesta.xyz"
           cd "$k" || exit 3
           echo '<<COMMANDS>>'
           cd - "$OLDPWD"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I would change a few other things in the script: **1:** The `#!` line is missing. **2:** Inconsistency in style `for` and `do` are on the same line, but `if` and `then` are not. Pick one style and stick with it. **3:** Body of the `for` loop did not get indented. **3:** Excessive whitespace within the `[` `]` construct. **4:** Missing `"` around most expansions of `$k` (it is not strictly needed here, but I think it would be a good habbit to get into.)

Comment: user1700494 and kasperd , thanks for your comments. The script is good now. I will consider your suggestions for the next ones.